# deactivating FormsAuthentication ticket

Tags: c#, asp.net, forms-authentication

I have some misunderstanding with forms authentication. For example my app has many employees and one of them is retired. But his user information is needed for documantation. so i just disable his account. but how can i make all his authentication tickets in all browsers became deactivated so that he cannot to use my app like authorised user?

Comment: The short answer is, you can't. Your application should be checking to ensure that the user who is trying to access the system is still an active user in the system.

Comment: it checkes if he is active when he logges on. but how to check his auth ticket?

Comment: If he's no longer active how does he even log on? There's no need to check the auth ticket because it never gets issued because he's no longer active so you don't issue the auth ticket.

Comment: for exaple I the user had credentials and logged on at some browser. then he was retired. so that he can make some problem to my DB. so that i need to check is he active

Comment: Yes, your application should check on every access that the user is still active in the system. That has nothing to do with the auth ticket though. We're just going in circles here at this point. The application issues the ticket but it must still check that the user (not the ticket) is valid on every request. It has nothing to do with disabling/invalidating the auth ticket.